# dom-repeat with parameterized template

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

What is the **clean way**, with Polymer **2.0**, to parameterize the dom-repeat item template ?

Usage:

```
<custom-component>
    <template id="item-template">
        [[item]]
    </template>
</custom-component>
```

CustomComponent:

```
<dom-module id="custom-component">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[foo]]" id="repeater">
            <!-- Parameterized template -->
        </template>
    </template>
    <!-- scripts... -->
</dom-module>
```

I cannot find any clear documentation on Polymer 2.0 to achieve this.

Comment: Please give an example of how you are going to use it. It is not clear what you want to achieve in a first place.

Answer (score 0):

I just new to learn polymer.Maybe I just your question.I guess you want to repeat an element which has the structure and data depends on want you need it to be.
And there are 3 points.

**demo-element.html**

```
<dom-moudle is="demo-element">
  <template>
    <span>{{property1.name}}</span>
    <span>{{property1.age}}</span>
    <script>
      class DemoElement extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'demo-element'; }
        static get properties() {
          return {
            property1: Object
          }
        }
      }
      window.customElements.define(DemoElement.is, DemoElement);
    </script>
  </template>
</dom-moudle>
```

**custom-component.html**

```
<dom-module id="custom-component">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[foo]]" id="repeater">
        <demo-element property1="[[item]]"></demo-element>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

1. [Dom-repeat's item property will be set on each instance's binding scope](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomRepeat),so you can not set dom-repeat's item property in `custom-component's` instance.
2. Create a custom element with the structure and data as you need.Repeat the custom element with `dom-repeat`.
3. [slot](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom#slot-apis) element is always suitable for Polymer.If you need to let `custom-component` include some other elements you should use placeholder.